# Using ParametricPlot to Display result of Maximize

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization, replacement

One would expect that:

```
Plot[f[x],{x,0,1/2}]
```

and

```
ParametricPlot[{x,f[x]},{x,0,1/2}]
```

would always yield identical outputs. For simple examples it does, **however**, in my case the function f is complicated:

```
g[x_,y_]:= 2*x*Piecewise[{{4/5 *(1 - 2 *x),0 < x < (10*y-1)/8)},{-(8/9) (-1 + x + y), (10*y-1)/8 <= x <=(1+8*y)/10},{1-2*x, (1+8*y)/10<=x<=1/2}}]
f[x_]:= y /. Maximize[{g[x,y],y>0},y][[2]]
```

Plot works fine but ParametricPlot returns the error **{y} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a dispatch table and so it can not be used for replacing**

I really need to be able to use ParametricPlot since I want to plot the inverse function. Any hints or suggestions?

Comment: Could you please explain what you are trying the `f[x]` to be in words?

Comment: @MathX f[x] is the value of y that maximizes a function g[x,y] where x is a given parameter, if g[x,y] is a simple function say g[x_,y_]:=-(x-y)^2 then everything works fine but g[x,y] itself is a piecewise function

Comment: Well in that case `f[x_] := y /. Last@Maximize[g[x, y], y]` might work. However, since you defined `flx]` as a set delayed function containing `Maximize`, it tries to maximize every time. Why not do this symbolically once and then use the resulting function in your plot?

Comment: Have you looked at `Reduce[{D[g[x, y], y] == 0, y > 0, 0 < x < 1/2}, y]`? (After fixing the syntax error in your `g`, of course.)

Comment: @J.M. Sorry for any typos in the g function, is there a way to copy and paste Mathematica code here instead of re-typping?

Comment: I solved the problem my using  f[x_]:=ArgMax[ g[x,y],y] -- it seems the replacement rules in the original definition of f were part of the problem.

Comment: A usual procedure is to right click on the selected expression, then Copy As > Input Text on the popup menu, then paste it here.